# Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 error?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, xcode4.3, box2d

I have XCode 4.3.3
I've download one project and it can't be run. I got an error:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

tell me anyone plz how can i solve this problem? 
[my screen over here](http://s002.radikal.ru/i198/1210/0c/97037ef9a56d.png)

Comment: I can't see your screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the log where it says you are missing the file **BBox2DBuilder.mm**, its above the red text in your image.